# Umbraco Navigation using XSLT macro - issue with childless nodes

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have implemented the [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) navigation menu into an umbraco installation.  Superfish simply takes a UL element and turns it into a hierarchical menu that shows child items when you hover over the parent (you remember when they were cool back in 1999 right?).

I cannot figure out why, on certain pages (usually ones without children), the menu does not show child items for any page.  My exposure to XSLT is minimal, so i must be overlooking some logic.

You can see the actual site [here](http://lsfitcouk00.eweb701.discountasp.net/)  Hover over 'personal training' to see the menu work, now click on 'weight management' and hey-presto the magic stops happening.

The XSLT that creates the UL structure is below, and the HTML page source tells me that its simply not generating any LI elements for child pages when the issue occurs.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage" />

<!--This sets the level that the nav starts at and tells us if we should recurse through child elements-->
<xsl:variable name="startDepth" select="/macro/startingLevel" />
<xsl:variable name="recurse" select="/macro/recurse" />
<xsl:variable name="selectBranches" select="/macro/selectBranches"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="maxMenuDepth" select="/macro/maxMenuDepth"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="forceNode" select="/macro/forceNode"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="walkChildren" select="/macro/expandChildren"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="forceHome" select="/macro/forceHome"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="securityTrimming" select="/macro/securityTrimming"></xsl:variable>
<!--Alternate page title variable in here-->

<!--Styles for the navigation-->
<xsl:variable name="ulBaseClass" select="/macro/ulBaseClass"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="branchClass" select="/macro/branchClass"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="selectedClass" select="/macro/selectedClass"></xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="startLevel">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$startDepth >= 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="$startDepth"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@level"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

  <!--This calls first iteration of the navigation, sending the first node at the correct depth found in the ancestors of the current page-->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$forceNode">
      <xsl:variable name="currentNode" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($forceNode)"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="nodeIterator">
        <xsl:with-param name="parentNode" select="$currentNode/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=$startLevel]
                        [
                          string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'
                          and ($securityTrimming != '1'
                            or umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false()
                            or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())
                        ]" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pseudoCurrentPage" select="$currentNode" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="currentNode" select="$currentPage"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="nodeIterator">
        <xsl:with-param name="parentNode" select="$currentNode/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=$startLevel]
                        [
                          string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'
                          and ($securityTrimming != '1'
                            or umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false()
                            or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())
                        ]" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pseudoCurrentPage" select="$currentNode" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nodeIterator">
    <xsl:param name="parentNode" />
    <xsl:param name="pseudoCurrentPage" />
    <!-- do not show info doc node types-->
  <xsl:variable name="calculatedMenuDepth" select="($parentNode/@level - $startLevel)+1" />

  <xsl:if test="$parentNode/*[@isDoc] or ($calculatedMenuDepth = 1 and $forceHome)">
    <ul>

      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$calculatedMenuDepth = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$ulBaseClass" />
          </xsl:when>
          <!--<xsl:when test="$calculatedMenuDepth = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($ulBaseClass, ' lv', $calculatedMenuDepth)" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$calculatedMenuDepth > 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $calculatedMenuDepth)" />
          </xsl:when>-->
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:if test="$forceHome = 1 and $calculatedMenuDepth = 1">
        <!-- Create the class for the li element-->
        <li>
          <xsl:variable name="isHomeSelected">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=1]/@id = $currentPage/@id">1</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:call-template name="cssClassConstructor">
            <xsl:with-param name="isSelected" select="$isHomeSelected" />
            <xsl:with-param name="isSelectedBranch" select="0" />
            <xsl:with-param name="hasChildren" select="1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="selectedClass" select="$selectedClass" />
            <xsl:with-param name="branchClass" select="$branchClass" />
          </xsl:call-template>

          <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=1]/@id)}">

            <xsl:call-template name="cssClassConstructor">
              <xsl:with-param name="isSelected" select="$isHomeSelected" />
              <xsl:with-param name="isSelectedBranch" select="0" />
              <xsl:with-param name="hasChildren" select="0" />
              <xsl:with-param name="selectedClass" select="$selectedClass" />
              <xsl:with-param name="branchClass" select="$branchClass" />
            </xsl:call-template>

            <!--set the innerText for the a element-->
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=1]/text()"/>

            <xsl:if test="string($currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=1]/text()) = ''">
              <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@level=1]/@nodeName"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </a>
        </li>
      </xsl:if>
      <!--End force home-->


      <!--for each node in the parent node that is not hidden by Umbraco-->
      <xsl:for-each select="$parentNode/*[@isDoc][
                          string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'
                          and ($securityTrimming != '1'
                            or umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false()
                            or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())
                        ]">

        <!--Set the current node id i.e. the node we have looped to not the current page-->
        <xsl:variable name="currentNodeID" select="@id" />

        <!--Is the node a branch? i.e. are there children and is it in the colletion of ancestor nodes -->
        <xsl:variable name="isBranch">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@id = $currentNodeID]/child::*[@isDoc]">1</xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!--Is the node selected? i.e. is it the same as the currentPage node-->
        <xsl:variable name="isSelected">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$currentPage/@id = $currentNodeID">1</xsl:when>
            <!-- parent selected -->
            <xsl:when test="$pseudoCurrentPage/@id = $currentNodeID">1</xsl:when>

          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="isSelectedBranch">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$isBranch = 1 and $selectBranches = 1">1</xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="hasChildren">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./*[@isDoc]">1</xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <li>

          <!-- Create the class attribute for the element-->
          <xsl:call-template name="cssClassConstructor">
            <xsl:with-param name="isSelected" select="$isSelected" />
            <xsl:with-param name="isSelectedBranch" select="$isSelectedBranch" />
            <xsl:with-param name="hasChildren" select="$hasChildren" />
            <xsl:with-param name="selectedClass" select="$selectedClass" />
            <xsl:with-param name="branchClass" select="$branchClass" />
          </xsl:call-template>

          <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">

            <xsl:call-template name="cssClassConstructor">
              <xsl:with-param name="isSelected" select="$isSelected" />
              <xsl:with-param name="isSelectedBranch" select="$isSelectedBranch" />
              <xsl:with-param name="hasChildren" select="0" />
              <xsl:with-param name="selectedClass" select="$selectedClass" />
              <xsl:with-param name="branchClass" select="$branchClass" />
            </xsl:call-template>

            <!--set the innerText for the a element-->
            <xsl:value-of select="./pageTitle/text()"/>
            <xsl:if test="string(./pageTitle/text()) = ''">
              <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </a>

          <!-- if it's a branch recurse through it's children-->
          <xsl:if test="((($isBranch = 1 and $recurse = 1) or ($walkChildren = 1 and $pseudoCurrentPage/descendant-or-self::*[@isDoc][@id = $currentNodeID]/child::*[@isDoc])) and $maxMenuDepth &gt; $calculatedMenuDepth)">
            <xsl:call-template name="nodeIterator">
              <xsl:with-param name="parentNode" select="." />
              <xsl:with-param name="pseudoCurrentPage" select="$pseudoCurrentPage" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>

        </li>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </ul>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="cssClassConstructor">
    <xsl:param name="isSelected"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="isSelectedBranch"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="hasChildren"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedClass"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="branchClass"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="class">
      <xsl:if test="$isSelected = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($selectedClass,' ')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$isSelectedBranch = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($branchClass,' ')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$hasChildren = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'hasChildren '"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($class) > 0">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($class)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>​
```

Comment: You have forgotton to provide something very important: the XML document which is being transformed. Please, do so. Also, please provide the expected result of the transformation on this XML document, the result you are actually getting and what difference between the actual and expected results you consider a problem.

Comment: that would suggest that you dont work with umbraco?  as the xml document is exposed by the umbraco framework and is an xml list of the pages within the site.  such as....  <xsl:variable name="currentNode" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($forceNode)"></xsl:variable>

Comment: @Baldy: No, I don't work with Umbraco, but I would like to help with the XSLT problem. This is only possible if you provide the necessary information. Never suppose that readers of the xslt tag should know anything about Umbraco.

Comment: ok, i will have to work out how to invoke the umbraco library method that exposes the xml and capture it in the debugger.  bear with me...!

Comment: @Baldy: Sure, just notify me with a further comment when the XML is available.

Comment: @Baldy: you can find the raw XML inside /data/umbraco.config or /App_Data/umbraco.config, depending on the version of Umbraco you're running.

Also, the issue you describe at the above link isn't there. I click on Weight Management, the menu still works (tested using Chrome 11). You have a bug with your top-right-corner image though, which prevents me moving properly over the "Join" menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you describe above isn't replicating for me (I've checked your source code using Notepad++ and a diff viewer). I see from your code that you're using the CogWorks' Flexible Navigation package. Can you ensure you're using the latest code from [here](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cogworks-flexible-navigation)?

Many thanks,

Benjamin

Comment: Hey Benjamin.  I solved the issue by rebuilding my own xslt file from scratch (bit of a hack, but it worked).  Not sure which version is running as the project has now shipped and is out of my hands.  You get the answer for your comments on my original question which help with debugging in general. cheers :)